# Word 365 on RDS does not open

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, windows-server-2012, rds

I just installed a new W2012R2 server with RDS and Office 365 ProPlus. I can open Word correctly. I added it to my RemoteApps but when I try to open Word from my local PC by going to the RDS website (RDWeb) it only opens a window of RemoteApp. If I am fast enough I see that it logs in into my server but it goes away that fast that I cannot see if it gives me an error or warning.
The other programs (calculator, paint) open directly.

Is there some way I can check what is going wrong? I already checked eventvwr on both my machines. Or does somebody knows what I could check to make this work?

Comment: Was there nothing in event viewer? There should be something. Make sure to check system, security and application. Security should at least be showing a successful connection/login, you should be able to trace more of the connection from that point on.

Comment: I think word has licensing checks that prevents it from being used in a terminal server environment

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out that I needed to take a look further on the server. There I found different things that need to be configured still, which I have done. I can publish several applications and open them without any problem but the Word still causes me headaches. In the Servers Events I see a Warning 20499: RDS has taken too long to load the user configuration from server \\DCSERVER for user USERNAME. Somebody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the published Word and readding it again helped me to get this solved.