# Published app calling Microsoft Word for a merge and failing

Tags: microsoft-word, remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

We run a published app on an RDS 2019 server. This works perfect, however when a specific function is used to create a mail merge to Word (it pulls client data, and job info and sets up a template) there is an error and word doesn't open, as per;

> An error occurred during the merge process. Ex: Call was rejected by callee.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

If we use the full desktop experience to log on to this RDS server, run their app and then attempt the mail merge, it works perfectly. Word opens, the info is inserted, and all is well.

I've also attempted to publish a batch file that opens Word, and their app. This does indeed open both applications, but the same error persists.
FWIW their app is a SQL DB based, only the published app has this issue, and there is nothing in the event log at all perhaps indicating what is failing.

Hoping someone has seen something similar here.

Comment: Have you contacted the supplier of your software? See also https://superuser.com/questions/899206/word-365-on-rds-does-not-open?rq=1

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I have indeed asked the Software support crowd, so far they do not know why. Word is correctly licensed (Office standard, through Volume Licensing) and works both in full remote desktop, as well as individually published. I also created a published app to a batch file, opening both the app, and Word. It opens both fine, but the error persists. It feels like some sort of permission issue.